# Write an object containing an array of objects to a mongo database in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my user collection, I have an object that contains an array of contacts.
The object definition is below.
How can this entire object, with the full array of contacts, be written to the user database in Meteor from the server, ideally in a single command?
I have spent considerable time reading the mongo docs and meteor docs, but can't get this to work.
I have also tried a large number of different commands and approaches using both the whole object and iterating through the component parts to try to achieve this, unsuccessfully.  Here is an (unsuccessful) example that attempts to write the entire contacts object using $set:

```
    Meteor.users.update({ _id: this.userId }, {$set: { 'Contacts': contacts}});
```

Thank you.

Object definition (this is a field within the user collection):

```
"Contacts" : {
    "contactInfo" : [
        {
            "phoneMobile" : "1234567890", 
            "lastName" : "Johnny"
            "firstName" : "Appleseed"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This update should absolutely work. What I suspect is happening is that you're not publishing the `Contacts` data back to the client because Meteor doesn't publish every key in the current user document automatically. So your update is working and saving data to mongo but you're not seeing it back on the client. You can check this by doing `meteor mongo` on the command line then inspecting the user document in question.

Try:

server:

```
Meteor.publish('me',function(){
  if (this.userId) return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, { fields: { profile: 1, Contacts: 1 }});
  this.ready();
});
```

client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('me');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  The code that I posted to write data doesn't work, it's not just that I'm not correctly seeing the result.  Not sure why it doesn't work.  I've been verifying this by checking the contents of the database directly using database tools (eg MongoChef).  Also, I have working publications that additionally verify that the update hasn't happened.  When I get a (different kind of) update to work, the client side correctly shows the change.  Also, can you LMK what commands to use for read/write in meteor mongo for testing this?  Thanks again...

Comment: In mongo try `db.user.find('yourIdHere')` and you should see that object in the console output. Please also `console.log(contact)` in your code before the update to verify what's there.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It turns out that the problem was with Simple Schema validation... a typo in a field name.

Answer (score -1):

The command above is correct.  The issue is schema verification.  Simple Schema was defeating the ability to write to the database while running 'in the background'.  It doesn't produce an error, it just fails to produce the expected outcome.